Software to keep track of open ports on my hosts
I have a VPN intranet with some hosts opening ports to the Internet for things like web sites.  I'd like to keep track of what ports are open on both interfaces (VPN, public) for each host, and be alerted to changes.  I have firewalls running on each host but they could be down unexpectedly.
Does automated, open-source software to monitor ports open on each host in a network exist?
